How can I change pytest's working directory?
I want to run the test if started via Visual Studio Code in the same directory as started from command line with pytest tests.
The folder structure is as follows:
project-root
|- .vscode
   - settings.json
|-data-processing
| |-src
| |-tests

I run pytest from data-processing folder pytest tests with os.getcwd() yielding:
...project-root/data-processing

If I run from VS Code os.getcwd() yields:
...project-root

With this setup (settings.json):
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "data-processing/tests",
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}

I tried to use python.testing.cwd option to set working directory:
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests",
    ],
    "python.testing.cwd": "./data-processing/",
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}

The problem is as soon as I set cwd the test discovery stops working - no test discovered at all. I tried different paths with and without "./". I also checked microsoft/vscode-python#22504.
So how to get the same working directory in VS Code for test runs? Changing the directory with os.chdir is not working since my problem is due to module resolution from within pyspark.
